# Node js app bluemix deployment error

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I try to deploy my node app on bluemix using cf. It says done uploading but then failed and error uploading application and an unknown error occurred. I am not sure where the problem is. I have mentioned the npm and node versions in my package.json file. Has it got to do anything with the fact that I am using socket.io in my app?

Comment: Can you run the app locally? What do the logs say?

Comment: Ya I am able to run it locally. I am actually unaware of how to set the CF_TRACE to be true. I am new to this.

Comment: You can do the command `cf logs APP_NAME` or you can go to Bluemix and click the Logs button to check it out.

Comment: Are you pushing your application with the `node_modules` folder? If you are, I would suggest deleting the entire `node_modules` folder and repushing.

Comment: I just deployed an app successfully via the Bluemix UI.  Are you using DevOp Services?